Domain of dependence of null segments
If $N$ is the null segment, in Minkowski spacetime, defined on the light cone $t = -x$ with $x \in [0,1]$, what would be its domain of dependence?
My answer: the domain of dependence would be $N$ itself:
Causal future of $N$, $J^+(N)$ = intersection of the regions given by $t \ge -x$, $t \le x$ and $t \ge x - 2$.
Similarly, causal past of $N$, $J^-(N)$ = intersection of the regions given by $t \le -x$, $t \le x$ and $t \ge x - 2$.
So the domain of dependence $D(N) = J^+(N) \cap J^-(N) = \{(t,x)\ |\ t = -x, x \in [0,1] \}$.
Is this correct?

The result is correct but the procedure is wrong. According to your idea you would find that the domain of dependence of the spacelike segment $x\in [0,1]$, $t=0$ is the segment itself….

@ValterMoretti Thanks for your reply. Could you also mention what I got wrong in defining the domain of dependence?

The definition of domain of dependece $D(S)$
of $S$ (usually achronal) is the set of spacetime events such that every inextendible causal curve passing through any of them also meets S somewhere. The intersection $J^+(S)\cap J^−(S)$ is instead made of the events $e$  such that there are two causal curves (possibly the same) which pass through $e$  and meet $S$.

I understand that I should have computed $D^+(N) \cup D^-(N)$ instead of the intersection of the causal past and causal future. But I am not aware of how to compute $D^\pm(S)$ when $S$ is a null segment. Any reference or hint on how to proceed would be helpful. Thanks!

Use the fact that, in Minkowski spacetime, there is a future directed causal  curve from $e$ to $e’$ if and only if there is a future directed causal segment form $e$ to $e’$. To define $D^+(N)$, consider the set of events $e$ such that every causal segment through $e$ meets $N$ before reaching $e$ (at most exactly at $e$).

Thanks, this was useful. Did I understand your statement correctly in saying that the collection of such events $e$ are the points on $N$ itself? The crucial point was every causal curve from $e$ had to also meet $N$ before $e$. A similar argument for $D^-(N)$ also implies that it is also equal to $N$. So the domain of dependence $D(N)$ is $N$. Did I get you right?

Yes, you have understood well.
